# Xcode -- have a macro behave differently depending on whether it is included from a .h file or a .m file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, gcc, macros

I want to have a macro SomeMacro(city, country) in a file that will be in a file MacroFile.h that I will #include from either a .h file or a .m file.  And I want SomeMacro to become something different depending on whether the file immediately above MacroFile.h in the include tree is a .h file or a .m file.  I want to do this without defining a special constant in the .m file.  Is that possible?

In pseudo-code, what I want MacroFile.h to do is this:

```
#if (file from which I was directly included is a .h)
#define SomeMacro(city, country) SomeStuffInvolvingCityAndCountry
#else
#define SomeMacro(city, country) SomeDifferentStuffInvolvingCityAndCountry
#endif

SomeMacro(washington, USA)
SomeMacro(tokyo, Japan)
SomeMacro(berlin, Germany)
```

Bonus points if you can also get MacroFile.h to examine what is two levels above it in the include tree.

EDIT: If there is a way for the macro to tell whether or not it is being called from inside an @implementation block, that would be good enough.

Comment: I don't think the C preprocessor lets you do that, and I don't think the GNU preprocessor has an extension that lets you do that. It might help if you told us what you're actually trying to achieve...

Comment: Agree that we need to know more about what is trying to accomplished to help properly, but otherwise, why not just define two different Macro.h files each containing the macro you want and include the appropriate file in the appropriate places?

Comment: I want to use the macros to define headers and implementations for getters and setters where I get/set the property by accessing another object.  I find myself doing this kind of forwarding a lot.  In order to keep down proliferation of files, it is far better if I can have one set of forwarding macros per class, not two.

Comment: I question that approach. Code that works different but looks the same is evil.  And headers might get included here and there without much thought.

Comment: Don't try to be smart. Be as clear and expressive as you can.

Answer (score 0):

There is no preprocessor test to determine where the macro is being expanded from.  `.h` is a convention for a header file, but has no semantic value.

You could create two files `MacroFile-header.h` and `MacroFile-code.h` as follows:

**MacroFile-header.h**:

```
// definitions
#define CityCountryMacro(city, country)  SomeStuffInvolvingCityAndCountry
#define StateZipMacro(state, zip)        SomeStuffInvolvingStateAndZip
```

**MacroFile-code.h**:

```
// undefine MacroFile-header.h macros
#if defined(CityCountryMacro)
    #undef CityCountryMacro
#endif
#if defined(StateZipMacro)
    #undef StateZipMacro
#endif

// definitions
#define CityCountryMacro(city, country)  OtherStuffInvolvingCityAndCountry
#define StateZipMacro(state, zip)        OtherStuffInvolvingStateAndZip
```

Always import `MacroFile-header.h` in your header files, as follows:

**SomeObject.h**:

```
#import "MacroFile-header.h"

// use macros
```

and `MacroFile-code.h` **after** all other imports, in your implementation:

**SomeObject.m**:

```
#import "SomeObject.h"
#import ...
#import ...

// always include last
#import "MacroFile-code.h"

// use macros
```